# nohup sends eof (or some other data) info my app when running recursively. How to make it stop or not send at all?

Tags: linux, nohup

I have a simple small app that suports `cin`/`cout` interaction. But there are times (lots of them) when I do not care about that interaction and just want to run my app in background. So I start it with command like

```
nohup ./myServer >& /dev/null &
```

but it eats 100% of one of my cores because `nohup` sends `eof` then `endl` or something like that to my app, my app thinks that this is dull user and proposes him with list of interaction commands and waits for new commad, nohup sends `eof` then `endl` again and so on recursively.

So one core gets eaten up with this crappy interaction. I want to start nohup so that it would send no data at all to my app - no `eof`, `endl`, etc how to do such thing?

How to make nohup send no data at all to my app after it started it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for that is to fix your application.

`nohup` doesn't send anything to anyone. Your application on the other hand is assuming that `stdin` is a valid, open file descriptor. It should be checking the return code of whatever primitive it is using to get the data from standard input, and react accordingly if the input stream is found to be closed or invalid.

Since you say `cin`, I'm going to assume you're coding in C++. 
This is a safe way of getting strings from `std::cin`

```c++
void get_input()
{
    std::cout << "getting input" << std::endl;

    std::string input;
    while (std::cin >> input) {
        // Good, got something from cin
        std::cout << " * " << input << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "out of input loop" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::cin.eof() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::cin.bad() << std::endl;
}
```

This is a *bad* way of getting user input:

```c++
void bad_input()
{
    std::cout << "getting input" << std::endl;

    std::string input;
    while (!std::cin.bad()) {
        std::cin >> input;  // BAD: not checking if the extractor succeeded
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
        // do stuff
    }

    // Not reached if `std::cin` reaches EOF
    std::cout << "out of input loop" << std::endl;
}
```

Since a stream at `eof` isn't `bad()`, this will loop forever once `cin` reaches OEF. There are many variations for this (both good and bad versions), and similar problems can arise in plain C (and many other languages) for similar reasons.